# SQL Server Index over lookup table of distinct values

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am trying to speed up the following SQL Server query:

```
    SELECT  
        V.Id, V.Number, V.VisitDate, V.ArrivalTime, V.VisitKindId, VK.Description AS 
        VisitKindDescription, 
        VK.DescriptionAr AS VisitKindDescriptionAr, V.StatusId, V.Note, V.CancelingReason, 
        V.CancelingTime, V.EnterToDoctorRoomTime, 
        V.PatientId, P.Number AS PatientNumber, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.BirthDate, P.Note AS 
        PatientNotes, V.DoctorId, D.FullName AS DoctorFullName, V.CreatedById, 
        U.FullName AS UserFullName, V.CreationDate, V.VersionNo
    FROM    
        Patient_Tbl P INNER JOIN
        Visit_Tbl V ON P.Id = V.PatientId INNER JOIN
        VisitKind_Tbl VK ON V.VisitKindId = VK.Id INNER JOIN
        Doctor_Tbl D ON V.DoctorId = D.Id INNER JOIN
        User_Tbl U ON V.CreatedById = U.Id INNER JOIN
        VisitStatus_Tbl VS ON V.StatusId = VS.Id
    WHERE V.StatusId = 2 --patient is in doctor room
```

and we had the following 4 values the VisitStatus_Tbl:
(1 -> In Waiting Room, 2 -> In Doctor Room, 3 -> Canceled, 4 -> Completed)

and in one moment of time, there is only one record on the Visits table for one person in the doctor's room.

The end-user inform me that there is a delay in the use case that depends on the above query.
Please help us speed system performance by suggesting the proper index.

Thanks,

Comment: Post your query execution plan, anbd perhaps your table schemas. Without it, it's just guess work. If there's only 1 row in your visits table, and 4 rows in your VisitStatus table, the issues must be the Doctor or Patients tables. With tiny rowcounts like you described, indexing would be pointless on either the Visits or VisitsStatus tables, as the engine would just do a table scan and suck those rows into memory.

Answer (score -1):

You do not indicate if you have any indexes on the tables now. I will assume that the 'ID' columns for patient_tbl, etc are clustered primary keys or just primary keys and have indexes.  If not, that is another problem.

Simple rule:  start with index foreign keys (lookup tables) and WHERE clauses.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_visit_tbl_statusid ON visit_tbl(statusId)
CREATE INDEX ix_visit_tbl_patientid ON visit_tbl(patientId)
CREATE INDEX ix_visit_tbl_visitkindId ON visit_tbl(visitkindId)
CREATE INDEX ix_visit_tbl_doctorid ON visit_tbl(doctorId)
CREATE INDEX ix_visit_tbl_createdbyid ON visit_tbl(createdbyId)
```

Now for the comments on how that is too many indexes.  It depends ...